# MySQL won't start after forcing it to stop

Tags: mysql, data-recovery

I put my site on maintenance so no one can access it and no new data will come into the database. I was running a query to delete 3 month old data from a table which took almost an hour at which I tried to stop it but it didn't work so I terminated `MySQLd.exe` via the process manager.

When I tried to start the server again, it just wont. Services is showing `starting...`

I checked the logs and found out InnoDB is trying to recover data due to a crash. But its also taking too long, its almost been 3 hours and still nothing.

The table I was deleting data from was a log table and I can live with it losing all its data.

Is there a way to force Mysql to start?

My logs for reference: (this is a new log I just stopped and started MySQL again)

```
2018-09-28 23:01:13 1236 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2018-09-28 23:01:13 1236 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-09-28 23:01:13 1236 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-09-28 23:01:13 1236 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-09-28 23:01:13 1236 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2018-09-28 23:01:13 1236 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 26G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2018-09-28 23:01:15 1236 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-09-28 23:01:15 1236 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-09-28 23:01:15 1236 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=778232557473
2018-09-28 23:01:29 1236 [Note] InnoDB: Read redo log up to LSN=778281119232
2018-09-28 23:01:45 1236 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 72237 pages from log
2018-09-28 23:05:48 1236 [Note] InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up in total 16171495 row operations to undo
2018-09-28 23:05:48 1236 [Note] InnoDB: Trx id counter is 678379008
2018-09-28 23:05:48 1236 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 69592 pages from redo log.
2018-09-28 23:05:48 17120 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 69591 pages from log
2018-09-28 23:06:03 17120 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 65851 pages from log
2018-09-28 23:06:17 10180 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 61926 pages from log
2018-09-28 23:06:32 11776 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 57757 pages from log
2018-09-28 23:06:47 10180 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 53071 pages from log
2018-09-28 23:07:02 11776 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 48887 pages from log
2018-09-28 23:07:17 12348 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 45023 pages from log
2018-09-28 23:07:33 12348 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 41053 pages from log
2018-09-28 23:07:47 11776 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 36623 pages from log
2018-09-28 23:08:02 12348 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 32688 pages from log
2018-09-28 23:08:17 17120 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 29057 pages from log
2018-09-28 23:08:32 17120 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 24964 pages from log
2018-09-28 23:08:47 12348 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 21520 pages from log
2018-09-28 23:09:02 12348 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 18192 pages from log
2018-09-28 23:09:17 17120 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 15020 pages from log
2018-09-28 23:09:32 10180 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 11971 pages from log
2018-09-28 23:09:47 11776 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 8775 pages from log
2018-09-28 23:10:03 17120 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 5464 pages from log
2018-09-28 23:10:17 11776 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 1857 pages from log
2018-09-28 23:10:26 1236 [Note] InnoDB: Last binlog file 'C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.2\data\mysql-bin.000578', position 1720
2018-09-28 23:10:27 1236 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2018-09-28 23:10:27 22188 [Note] InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of recovered transactions
2018-09-28 23:10:27 22188 [Note] InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 678377419, 16171495 rows to undo
2018-09-28 23:10:27 1236 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"

InnoDB: Progress in percents: 12018-09-28 23:10:27 1236 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2018-09-28 23:10:27 1236 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2018-09-28 23:10:27 1236 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2018-09-28 23:10:27 1236 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-09-28 23:10:27 1236 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.19 started; log sequence number 778528084534
2018-09-28 23:10:27 8332 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.2\data\ib_buffer_pool

...lots of more data... and lots of long semaphore wait

InnoDB: ###### Starts InnoDB Monitor for 30 secs to print diagnostic info: 
InnoDB: Pending reads 0, writes 0
InnoDB: ###### Diagnostic info printed to the standard error stream
2018-09-28 23:25:07 8332 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 180928 23:25:07
```

I noticed this line:

```
InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 678377419, 16171495 rows to undo
```

About 16M rows was the actual number of rows I was trying to delete from the log table.

Comment: By killing the query you forced InnoDB into recovery mode. Since it never got to complete the delete transaction, it's now rolling that back. Just give it time, unless you want to end up with a corrupt database altogether.

Comment: @Oldskool thanks but its been 3 hours and mysql still hasn't started yet. Still `starting...`

Comment: The log hasn't also updated anything. It ends at `InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 180928 23:25:07`

Comment: Just to update. This never ended. I was forced to delete everything and restore from a back up that was 20 hours old. Few hours of lost data is better than waiting for this to finish, I waited more than 24 hours for this.

Comment: might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25270601/1069083